# SQL Server: query results from another query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query below which return 124 rows to which I'm trying to count `Name` and return the value 124. Is there an easy way to query the results from this query or just add another column?

```
declare @Logins varchar(max)

Select 
    Name, UserName, CreationDate, TimeDataRetrieval, 
    TimeProcessing, TimeRendering, ByteCount, [RowCount], 
    path, TimeEnd, Format, 
    COUNT(*) over(partition by format) AS FormatCnt, 
    COUNT(NAME) AS HUH
From
    (SELECT      
        cat.Name, 
        SUBSTRING(ex.UserName, CHARINDEX('\', ex.UserName) + 1, 
        LEN(ex.UserName) - CHARINDEX('\', ex.UserName)) AS UserName, 
        cat.CreationDate, ex.TimeDataRetrieval, ex.TimeProcessing, 
        ex.TimeRendering, ex.ByteCount, ex.[RowCount], 
        cat.path, ex.TimeEnd, ex.Format
     FROM         
        ExecutionLog AS ex 
     INNER JOIN
        Catalog AS cat ON ex.ReportID = cat.ItemID) AS ZZ
--WHERE UserName in (@Logins)
--and
WHERE UserName = 'user1'
  AND (Path NOT LIKE '%Autodelivery%'
       AND Path NOT LIKE '%admin%'
       AND Path NOT LIKE '%qa%'
       AND path NOT LIKE '%test%')
GROUP BY 
   ZZ.UserName, ZZ.Name, ZZ.ByteCount, ZZ.CreationDate, ZZ.Format, ZZ.Path, 
   ZZ.[RowCount], ZZ.TimeDataRetrieval, ZZ.TimeEnd, ZZ.TimeProcessing, 
   ZZ.TimeRendering
ORDER BY 
   Name, TimeEnd DESC
```

Comment: if you want to just count distinct names and nothing else, then you can just do  `select distinct Name, count(Name) from table group by Name;`

Comment: Which column in your current result set contains the value you want? Is it "Name" or "Huh"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you could use this format...

```
declare @Logins varchar(max)

SELECT COUNT(a.name)
FROM (    
    Select Name, UserName, CreationDate, TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing,TimeRendering, ByteCount, [RowCount], path, TimeEnd, Format, COUNT(*) over(partition by format) AS FormatCnt, COUNT(NAME)AS HUH
    From
    (
    SELECT      cat.Name, SUBSTRING(ex.UserName, CHARINDEX('\', ex.UserName) + 1, LEN(ex.UserName) - CHARINDEX('\', ex.UserName)) AS UserName, 
                      cat.CreationDate, ex.TimeDataRetrieval, ex.TimeProcessing, ex.TimeRendering, ex.ByteCount, ex.[RowCount], cat.path, ex.TimeEnd, ex.Format
    FROM         ExecutionLog AS ex INNER JOIN
                      Catalog AS cat ON ex.ReportID = cat.ItemID
    ) AS ZZ
    --WHERE UserName in (@Logins)
    --and
    WHERE UserName = 'user1'
     and 
    (Path not like '%Autodelivery%'
        and Path not like '%admin%'
        and Path not like '%qa%'
        and path not like '%test%')
        GROUP BY ZZ.UserName, ZZ.Name, ZZ.ByteCount, ZZ.CreationDate, ZZ.Format, ZZ.Path, ZZ.[RowCount], ZZ.TimeDataRetrieval, ZZ.TimeEnd, ZZ.TimeProcessing, ZZ.TimeRendering
    --order by Name, TimeEnd desc
) a
```

Comment: I'm a little confused trying to format my query with your answer. Would I need to use another `SELECT`? Could you insert my query to how you think it should be structured?

Comment: Gave this error `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.` Removing the ORDER BY returns nothing however.

Comment: Edit: It's returning a name, then how many times it shows up. I'm trying to just count all combined. Add a * in there some where?

Comment: It's returning a name, then how many times it shows up. I'm trying to just count all combined. Add a * in there some where? So just 1 value